# Why are constants declared inside an array, and assigned to other constants, accessible as Class constants in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, constants

Given the following Ruby class

```
class Example
  PARENTS = [
    FATHER = :father,
    MOTHER = :mother
  ]
end
```

These work as expected

```
> Example::PARENTS
#=> [:father, :mother]
> Example::PARENTS[0]
#=> :father
> Example::PARENTS[1]
#=> :mother
```

However, why does this work?

```
> Example::FATHER
#=> :father
> Example::MOTHER
#=> :mother
```

In fact, why are there three constants in the Example class's scope?

```
> Example.constants
#=> [:MOTHER, :PARENTS, :FATHER]
```

To the point, that if I extend the class with an additional method:

```
class Example
  def self.whos_your_daddy
    FATHER
  end
end
```

It accesses the constant like normally.

```
> Example.whos_your_daddy
#=> :father
```

How is this behavior possible? By declaring the constants *inside* of an array, I would expect them to to be scoped inside the array. Please cite the relevant docs in your answer.

**Edit:** I suppose I'll clarify, the easiest way to answer this question is to explain two things:

First, what happens when the following code is executed:

```
PARENTS = [
  FATHER = :father,
  MOTHER = :mother
]
```

Second, does declare a constant anywhere tie it to the scope of the class it is being declared in? Why?

Comment: The visibility of the constants is given by `Example.constants
 => [:MOTHER, :PARENTS, :FATHER]`, [This article](https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/ruby_tutorial/The_Ruby_Language_Scope_of_Constants_and_Variables.html) provides a good explanation of the scope of constants.

Comment: @CarySwoveland the confusion in the question is a combination of the syntax used to declare the `PARENTS` constant, and because of a weak grasp on the scoping concepts. I suppose I should clarify this. I'm actually aware of the answer to the question. However, as pointed out already in the question, we already know the constants are in the class's scope, the question is: why?

Comment: Solution: Don't use weakly typed languages so such gotchas would be caught by the compiler before they ever crop up as a bug in production

Comment: Why do you think an array becomes the scope for a constant? Please cite the relevant docs that says that.

Comment: @sawa, please don't aggressively edit the question to the point where it's drastically different.

Comment: @ClickUpvote: Your comment doesn't seem to make much sense. Ruby is strongly typed. The question is about scope, so strong/weak typing isn't relevant anyway. Did you mean "dynamic"?

Comment: _"By declaring the constants inside of an array, I would expect them to to be scoped inside the array. Please cite the relevant docs in your answer."_ – could you cite the relevant docs that lead to your assumption? ;-)

Comment: @Stefan, haha, good catch — I can't. This question is one I hear when people see me use this kind of declaration in my service objects, and so I tried to reproduce the confusion as much as possible in the question. I'm sorry for the confusion. This Q&A post was finally created after [this question](https://www.toptal.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-service-objects-tutorial#comment-4322654659).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> First, what happens when the following code is executed:
>
> ```
> PARENTS = [
>   FATHER = :father,
>   MOTHER = :mother
> ]
> ```

- `PARENTS = ...` attempts to set the constant `PARENTS`. But in order to do so, it has to evaluate the right-hand side of the assignment:

  - `[...]` attempts to create an array. But in order to do so, it has to evaluate its arguments:

    - `FATHER = :father` sets the constant `FATHER` to `:father`. The result of this assignment is `:father` which becomes the first argument.
    - `MOTHER = :mother` sets the constant `MOTHER` to `:mother`. The result of this assignment is `:mother` which becomes the second argument.

So in *chronological* order:

1. The constant `FATHER` is set to `:father`
2. The constant `MOTHER` is set to `:mother`
3. An array with elements `:father` and `:mother` is created
4. The constant `PARENTS` is set to that array

Your code is equivalent to:

```
FATHER = :father
MOTHER = :mother
PARENTS = [FATHER, MOTHER]  # or [:father, :mother]
```

> By declaring the constants inside of an array, I would expect them to to be scoped inside the array. Please cite the relevant docs in your answer.

You can use `Module.nesting` to determine the current nesting, i.e. where a constant will be defined in: (more examples in the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/doc/syntax/modules_and_classes_rdoc.html#label-Constants))

```
class Example
  p outer_nesting: Module.nesting
  PARENTS = [
    p(inner_nesting: Module.nesting)
  ]
end
```

Output:

```
{:outer_nesting=>[Example]}
{:inner_nesting=>[Example]}
```

As you can see, an array literal doesn't affect the current nesting. Constants in both locations will be defined under `Example`.

If you really wanted to declare the constants "inside" the array (i.e. inside the array's singleton class), you could do some like this:

```
class Example
  PARENTS = []
  class << PARENTS
    FATHER = :father
    MOTHER = :mother
    PARENTS.push(FATHER, MOTHER)
  end
end

p Example.constants                          #=> [:PARENTS]
p Example::PARENTS.singleton_class.constants #=> [:FATHER, :MOTHER]
```

The above is just for demonstration purposes, there's no need to actually do that.

Comment: I came here to modify my answer with the exact same code as yours. Do you know how to reference `PARENTS` inside the singleton class without having to actually write `PARENTS`? `super` doesn't work outside of a method definition.

Comment: @EricDuminil i don't think you can retrieve an object from its singleton class, although that would be an interesting addition.

Comment: Let's [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54531270/retrieve-a-ruby-object-from-its-singleton-class)!

Answer (score 3):

I can understand how it can be confusing, but apart from the fact that reassigning values to constants is discouraged, in terms of scope — instance variables and constants are extremely similar.

The visual trick in the first class declaration is where you declare the constant inside an array.

First: understand that when you declare a constant, the returned value is your definition. E.g.

```
FATHER = :father
#=> :father
```

Now, let's look at the constant declaration:

```
PARENTS = [
  FATHER = :father,
  MOTHER = :mother
]
```

For declaring `PARENT`, you could have just used:

```
PARENTS = [
  :father,
  :mother
]
```

but you went a step further and declared a constant inside the definition as well. Now please understand that **the scope of instance variables and constants is similar**, it is tied to the instance it was declared in, and so **declaring a constant anywhere would tie it to the instance.**

By executing `FATHER = :father`, you've declared another constant, and the scope of a constant is always going to be the class it was declared in, in this case `Example`. The same is also true for `MOTHER = :mother`.

If you're more used to instance variables — it's the same reason this works: Given the following Ruby class.

```
class Example
  @parents = [
    @father = :father,
    @mother = :mother
  ]
end
```

These work as expected

```
> Example.instance_variable_get :@parents
#=> [:father, :mother]
> Example.instance_variable_get(:@parents)[0]
#=> :father
> Example.instance_variable_get(:@parents)[1]
#=> :mother
```

But this works too.

```
> Example.instance_variable_get :@father
#=> :father
> Example.instance_variable_get :@mother
#=> :mother
```

In fact, these three are in the Example class's scope.

```
> Example.instance_variables
#=> [:@mother, :@parents, :@father]
```

To the point, that if I extend the class with an additional method:

```
class Example
  def self.whos_your_daddy
    @father
  end
end
```

It accesses the instance variables like normally.

```
> Example.whos_your_daddy
#=> :father
```

Comment: "[T]he scope of instance variables and constants is similar"--Not at all.

Comment: @sawa How would you say not?

Answer (score 2):

I found this in the ruby ​​programming book, page 94:

> Constants defined within a class or module may be accessed unadorned anywhere within the class or module. Outside the class or module, they may be accessed using the scope operator, ::, prefixed by an expression that returns the appropriate class or module object. Constants defined outside any class or module may be accessed unadorned or by using the scope operator with no prefix. Constants may not be defined in methods. Constants may be added to existing classes and modules from the outside by using the class or module name and the scope operator before the constant name.

Conclusion, there cannot be two constants with the same name within a class, one inside the array and one outside. So you do not need the scope to access it, since the scope is the whole class.

You will not need a constant within a constant array, since the array being constant its internal values ​​are constant too.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question as your first one on the site, and welcome to Stack Overflow! :) There's a small bit of confusion in your answer — "there can not be two CONSTANTS with the same name". At no point did I use two constants with the same name.

Comment: Please provide the source as well. Which book was this? What version?

Answer (score 2):

A short answer could be that:

- Constants can only be stored inside [Modules](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Module.html) *. [`const_set`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Module.html#method-i-const_set) is defined for [Module](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Module.html), not [Object](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Object.html).
- [Classes](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Class.html) are [Modules](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Module.html).
- An Array instance isn't a Module.

Your code is equivalent to:

```
class Example
  PARENTS = [
    Example.const_set("FATHER", :father),
    Example.const_set("MOTHER", :mother)
  ] 
end
```

with some tests:

```
puts Example.is_a? Module
# true
puts Example.is_a? Class
# true
p Example::PARENTS
# [:father, :mother]
p Example.constants
# [:FATHER, :MOTHER, :PARENTS]
puts Example::PARENTS.is_a? Module
# false
Example::PARENTS.const_set("UNCLE", :uncle)
# undefined method `const_set' for [:father, :mother]:Array (NoMethodError)
```

<sub>*: Top-level constants (= constants defined outside a class or module) seem to be stored in `Object`.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is in your question.

```
class Example
  PARENTS = [
    FATHER = :father,
    MOTHER = :mother
  ]
end
```

Here 3 constants (`PARENTS`, `FATHER` and `MOTHER`). And they in one scope. Array doesn't make new scope.

And `Example.constants` method just shows you them.

Even if you add your method to your class it changes absolutely nothing

```
class Example
  PARENTS = [
    FATHER = :father,
    MOTHER = :mother
  ]

  def self.whos_your_daddy
    FATHER
  end
end

Example.constants #=> [:MOTHER, :PARENTS, :FATHER]
```

Comment: Your entire answer is almost just repetition of the OP's question, and adds no value. The only part that is useful is "Array doesn't make new scope".

Answer (score 0):

Array definition is not a block. It does not run in Array's scope.

It's no different from:

```
PARENTS = []
PARENTS << mom = :mother
```

As you can see, scope does not change:

```
> puts self
main
=> nil
> array = [ puts(self.inspect) ]
main
=> [nil]
```

Assignment returns the assigned value:

```
> foo = "bar"
"bar"
> puts foo
bar
> puts(foo = "baz")
baz
> puts foo
baz
```

You can't "store" something like `MOTHER = :mother` in an Array as it is not a value, it returns a value, which is `:mother`.