# Retrieve a Ruby object from its singleton class?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

It is possible to access a [singleton class](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Object.html) from a Ruby object with:

```
some_object.singleton_class
```

Is it possible to do the reverse operation : access the original object when inside the singleton class?

```
class << some_object
  # how to reference some_object without actually typing some_object?
end
```

I wanted to DRY this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54530568/6419007):

```
class Example
  PARENTS = []
  class << PARENTS
    FATHER = :father
    MOTHER = :mother
    PARENTS.push(FATHER, MOTHER)
  end
end
```

and tried to replace `PARENTS` inside the class with something more generic.

Comment: There's also [`singleton_class?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Module.html#method-i-singleton_class-3F) so a singleton class is quite aware of its special status.

Comment: _"without actually typing some_object"_ – it's even worse: if `some_object` is a local variable, it's not defined in the `class << some_object` block. Attempting to reference it within the block results in a `NameError`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Class#attached_object (Ruby 3.2+)

Starting from `Ruby 3.2`, there is a [Class#attached_object](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/Class.html#method-i-attached_object) method:

> Returns the object for which the receiver is the singleton class.
>
> Raises an [TypeError](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/TypeError.html) if the class is not a singleton class.

For example:

```rb
class Foo; end

Foo.singleton_class.attached_object     #=> Foo
Foo.attached_object                     #=> TypeError: `Foo' is not a singleton class
Foo.new.singleton_class.attached_object #=> #<Foo:0x000000010491a370>
TrueClass.attached_object               #=> TypeError: `TrueClass' is not a singleton class
NilClass.attached_object                #=> TypeError: `NilClass' is not a singleton class
```

**Sources:**

- [Class#attached_object](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/Class.html#method-i-attached_object).
- [Add Class#attached_object](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/pull/6450).
- [Feature #12084](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/12084).

Comment: Excellent, thanks! I just tested it. It seems to work fine with `attached_object.push(FATHER, MOTHER)`.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not aware of any built-in method or keyword but you could write a method that adds a (singleton) method to an object's singleton class, returning the object itself:

```
class Object
  def define_instance_accessor(method_name = :instance)
    singleton_class.define_singleton_method(method_name, &method(:itself))
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
obj = Object.new              #=> #<Object:0x00007ff58e8742f0>
obj.define_instance_accessor
obj.singleton_class.instance  #=> #<Object:0x00007ff58e8742f0>
```

In your code:

```
class Example
  PARENTS = []
  PARENTS.define_instance_accessor
  class << PARENTS
    FATHER = :father
    MOTHER = :mother
    instance.push(FATHER, MOTHER)
  end
end
```

---

Internally, YARV stores the object in an instance variable called `__attached__`. The instance variable doesn't have the usual `@` prefix, so it isn't visible or accessible from within Ruby.

Here's a little C extension to expose it:

```c
#include <ruby.h>

static VALUE
instance_accessor(VALUE klass)
{
    return rb_ivar_get(klass, rb_intern("__attached__"));
}

void Init_instance_accessor()
{
    rb_define_method(rb_cClass, "instance", instance_accessor, 0);
}
```

Usage:

```
irb -r ./instance_accessor
> obj = Object.new
#=> #<Object:0x00007f94a11e1260>
> obj.singleton_class.instance
#=> #<Object:0x00007f94a11e1260>
>
```

Comment: Excellent work with the C extension. I'm still hoping there's a a clean-ish plain Ruby solution, though.

Answer (score 2):

Just out of curiosity (please don’t use at home or school)

```
object = []
class << object
  type, id = to_s[/(?<=:#<).*?(?=>)/].split(':')
  ObjectSpace.each_object(Kernel.const_get(type)).find do |e|
    e.__id__ == id.to_i(16) >> 1
  end << :father
end   
#⇒ [:father]
```

Comment: @MarcinKołodziej yeah, it’s “how to turn all your teammates into violent enemies in 24 hours” :)

Answer (score 2):

We can do that as follows.

```
def singleton_class_to_object(sc)
  ObjectSpace.each_object(Object).find { |o|
    (o.singleton_class == sc) rescue false }
end

o = Object.new
  #=> #<Object:0x00005b52e502d030> 
singleton_class_to_object(o.singleton_class)
  #=> #<Object:0x00005b52e502d030> 

class C; end
singleton_class_to_object(C.singleton_class)
  #=> C
```

The in-line rescue is to deal with objects `o` that are immediate objects, having no singleton classes.

In MRI v2.7.0,

```
ObjectSpace.each_object(Object).to_a.size
  #=> 35362
```

a mere pittance.

Comment: Good idea. It's still not completely straightforward but it goes in the right direction, and without needing C.

Comment: It works fine with the original example : https://pastebin.com/DqJh9JuB Do you have any better idea for method name?

Comment: For the name, how about `ssalc_notelgnis`? I'm not sure you want to check if the argument is a singleton class within the method, but if you do perhaps raise an exception if it isn't. (Consider a guard clause rather than `if`: `raise ... unless singleton_class`.) Also, shouldn't that be defined in `Class` rather than `Module`?

Comment: Another idea is `singleton_class_of_what?`.